# Convert list into a list of 2-tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list:

```
list = [1, 2, 3]
```

I want to get this list and add a tuple so this list becomes like this

```
T_list = [(1,x), (2, x), (3,x)]
```

How do I do it?

Comment: What is `x`...?

Comment: Is `x` another list?

Comment: `[(value, x) for value in values]`

Answer (score 10):

Use a simple list comprehension to do this:

```
>>> your_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> x = 100
>>> your_list_with_tuples = [(k, x) for k in your_list]
>>> your_list_with_tuples
```

Output

```
[(1, 100), (2, 100), (3, 100)]
```

Also, don't name your variables `list`, `dict`, etc, because they shadow the builtin types/functions.

Answer (score 3):

A list comprehension would do the trick:

```
t_list = [(y,x) for y in original_list]
```

Also, the commenter is right. Don't name your lists `list`. It's a built in function. Using it for something else could cause problems down the line.

Comment: What do you mean by "reserved word"?

Comment: It has a specific meaning in Python. It creates a list from the iterator passed to it. Assigning something else to `list` could break that.

Comment: but `list` is just a built-in function. It's not reserved. It's not even a keyword. But the last part is True: "Assigning something else to `list` could break".

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt, although I'm not an expert.

```
lis = [1,2,3]
tup = (4, 5, 6)

new_tup = tuple(lis)
new_lis = []
for i in range(0,3):
    data = (new_tup[i],tup[i])
    new_lis.append(data)
print(new_lis)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code takes the numbers `1, 2, 3` and pairs each of them with the number `100`

```py
your_list = [1, 2, 3]
x = 100
your_list_with_tuples = []
for item in your_list:
    your_list_with_tuples.append((item, x))
print(your_list_with_tuples)
```